# What event can be captured when an HTML hidden input value is set / changed

Tags: javascript, html, controls, hidden

HI,
In JavaScript when value is set to a hidden input control, which event is fired?

Comment: Please clarify your question. It's unreadable, and unclear at the moment. 
Click on Edit and remake it.

Answer (score 22):

Whenever you change the value of a hidden field using script, it wont fire any event. But you can manually trigger the event if you are using jQuery.

Lets assume that you have the following hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" id="hid" value="0" 
onchange="alert('Caught the hidden event');" />
```

When you change the value of the field using following code, it will not display the alert message.

```
$("#hid").val("2");
```

But you can trigger the change event using the following code

```
$("#hid").val("2").change();
```

Above code will display the alert message.

Answer (score 2):

A value (aside from the initial value) can only be set on a hidden input by using scripting, and events do not generally fire in response to scripts.

It might trigger a [Mutation event](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/NOTE-DOM-Level-3-Events-20031107/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents), but browser support for them is not all that widespread yet.

In general, if you want to do something when you script changes the value of a hidden input — make the script do the other thing at the same time.

Answer (score -6):

I'm guessing that 'onchange' would fire.

Comment: Nope, onchange doesn't fire when changing the value from JS.