# Calling Javascript function from hidden field

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, dom-events

How can I call a Javascript function from a hidden field?

```
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnfield" onChange="callJsFunction()" runat="server" />
```

So what can replace onChange? because hiddenfield doesn't support onTextChanged...

Comment: When do you expect `onChange()` to happen for a hidden field.

Comment: What client side event makes the hidden field change?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does HTML Hidden control have any events? Like onchange or something?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003053/does-html-hidden-control-have-any-events-like-onchange-or-something). Also see a related Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026704/what-event-can-be-captured-when-an-html-hidden-input-value-is-set-changed. Short answer is NO!

Answer (score 1):

why can not you use

```
$('#<% hdnfield.Id %>').change( function() { alert("Changed"); })
```

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky to work with hidden fields. Try this listener i wrote. It worked for me in many different cases. I'm using jquery but you don't have to. This one is listening on value change but you can listen on any attribute.

**Let say you have hidden input with some initial value:**

```
<input id="change" type="hidden" value="SomeValue" />
```

**Script below will check that value every 2 ses and alert for changes:**

```
// Set empty global var for input value
inputValue = '';

    listenOnChange = function() {

    // Check for new value if any
    checkForNewInputValue = $('#change').val(); 

    if (inputValue == checkForNewInputValue) {

        // Check after 2 sec for change
        setTimeout("listenOnChange()",2000);

    } else {

        // Replace with new value
        inputValue = checkForNewInputValue;

        // Check after 2 sec for change
        setTimeout("listenOnChange()",2000);

        alert('IT WORKS');

    }
}
$(document).ready(
    inputValue = $('#change').val(), // Set Initial Value
    listenOnChange() // Start listener
);
```

**Button below will change that value. Copy, Paste and see how it works.**

```
<button onclick="$('#change').val('1234566');">CHANGE</button>
```